# using javascript to get Json Data (Google Api)/Trello

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get at some data that Trello is sending back to me into Google Apps Script for Spreadsheet.  The json looks like:

```
 date: "XXXXXX",
 type: "XXXXXX",
 memberCreator: {
     id: "XXXXXXX",
    avatarHash: "XXXXXXXXX",
    username: "XXXXXXX",
    initials: "XXX",
    fullName: "XXXXXXXXX"
```

I tried to get at it by using the following but it returns undefined (or NaN I think) and I can't use jQuery:

```
for(var j=0; j < singleCard.length; j++){
  var str = singleCard[j]["memberCreator"]["fullname"];
  if(str == "something"){
      Do something here;
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you paste your code with more details? What is `myJson`? What is `i`?

Comment: it's just an array of json objects is all you could date that out if you wanted to:  I'm just trying to get at memberCreator fullName

Comment: okay if you want assistance, you need to paste your code so that people can examine what could have possibly gone wrong. if what you're saying is true that it's just an array of json objects (implying a normal one which has no errors) then you're not supposed to get undefined.

Comment: okay I pasted more of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fullName` instead of `fullname` - object properties are case sensitive. Here:

```
for(var j=0; j < singleCard.length; j++){
  var str = singleCard[j]["memberCreator"]["fullName"];
  if(str == "something"){
      Do something here;
    }
 }
```

Comment: you were right about the case sensitive.  I figured out my error...the json I was trying to access was actually 3 deep ( just used 2 for simplicity's sake).  I was going for singleCard[j]['data']['memberCreator']['fullName'], but on some of the Json objects there was no 'fullName' so I just added to a if(singleCard[j]['data']['memberCreator']['fullName'] != undefined){} and that cleared it up.  Thanks people!  Sorry about the lack of code at first.